# How to move one image on top of other image circularly

Tags: javascript, css, html

[image] We need to create a screensaver where one image is fixed and second image should be moving continuously to the right such a way that when it moves to the right the left part where image is not present should be filled with the image again. We coded as shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Moving Screen Saver</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%
            }
            #bgimg {
                background-image: url("background/moon_bg.png");
                position: absolute;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #bdgimg {
                background-image: url("buildings/bdg6.png");
                position: absolute;
                background-color:transparent;
                bottom: 0px;
                left : 0px;
                width: 100%;
                /*height: 836px;*/
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bgimg">
        </div>
        <div id="bdgimg">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var bdg_img = document.getElementById('bdgimg');
            var animate;
            function moveRight()
            {
                bdg_img.style.left = bdg_img.style.left || 0;
                bdg_img.style.left = parseInt(bdg_img.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
                animate = setTimeout(moveRight,40); // call moveRight in 20msec
            }
            moveRight();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is moving the second image to the right as expected but not sure how to fill the left part. We need to create an effect like the image is moving continuously to the right but the image should be present on the left also. That means no vacant area should be present on the left because of the image moving. Can any one please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: For #bdgimg (the movig one) you would need css: z-index: 10 or smth, so that it comes above all.
Else, I'm not sure what's the problem as there is always #bgimg on the window.

Comment: @najuste: If you see the image I attached, the left side there is no top image because it is moved. But I need to display the image there which is getting cut because of moving right.

Comment: oh, I guess I understand.. You want the same image continuously roll over again and again (?)
I'm not an expert, but you could use one more same image positioned off the window, and you move both images. Once the whole length of the images is gone (1st image is offscreen at right), you would reposition it to left (by assigning class) and at the same time you would reduce the amount you went to left by the image width so that the images go offscreen just for certain time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you don't really need JavaScript and cloning for it. You can get away with simple `@keyframe` animations, animating the `background-position` as long as you get the correct value for repeating the loop continuously (`48.1vw,` in the example below - of course, it can be any multiple i.e.: `96.2vw`), to match the ratio of the image you use. For example:

```css
.animator {
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/car.svg);
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: move-background 3s linear infinite;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
@keyframes move-background {
  0% {
    background-position: 0vw, 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 48.1vw, 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animator"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrie Gheorghiu. But when I use this method after 3 seconds, there is an illusion like the screen is flickering.

Comment: @kadina That's what I meant by *"as long as you get the correct value for repeating the loop continuously"* You have to change your `100%` rule to a value that's correct for your image. Instead of `48.1vw` you need something around `65vw` ~ `75vw` from the looks of your image. Change it until you get it right. Or use `JavaScript` :)

Comment: Thanks @Andrie Gheorghiu. Not able to determine the exact number. If possible may I know how we can do in javascript?